# What is the meaning of DOCTYPE in xml file?

Tags: xml, hibernate, dtd

In hibernate we use configuration and mapping xml files.
In xml the first line will be version and then we specify DOCTYPE DTD line.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Can anybody please explain what is the meaning of this? 
I know that DTD is document type definition which is like defining grammar for the xml.

I want to know the attributes in this statement.

Answer (score 6):

The line you refer to is the *document type declaration*.

It is documented in the W3C's XML Recommendation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-doctype

It specifies a DTD that is to be used when processing the document. Two mechanisms are available for specifying this

1. an optional PUBLIC identifier (rare these
   days) which is, in your example, "
   -//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN". The mechanism by which this is resolved to a DTD resource
   is application-specific.
2. A SYSTEM
   identifier, which in your example is
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd".
   This is typically interpreted as a
   URL from where the DTD can be
   retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

A Doctype describes which DTD the XML file follows.

This:

1. Describes what elements are allowed inside what other elements (for the purpose of validation)
2. Describes what named character references are available (beyond the 5 XML built-ins of `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`).